# How to protect code from destructuring a null value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nullable, destructuring

I'm a big fan of destructuring and optional [chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) proposal in Javascript.

I couldn't help but feel that when destructuring a null or undefined value it'd be really useful if the result would be undefined as it is in optional chaining instead of throwing an error.

For example:

```
const person = null
console.log(person?.age) // undefined
```

However:

```
const person = null
const { age } = person // runtime error
```

It doesn't work like this of course but is there some Babel proposal to add this feature? Is there some workaround?

Comment: Is `const { age } person` supposed to be `const { age } = person` or are you trying to convey some sort of concept with this syntax?

Comment: It was a typo, I meant `const { age } = person`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you might just want to use `|| {}` to destructure an empty object in case `person` is is null (and happens to also apply if it's otherwise falsey too):

```js
const person = null
const { age } = person || {};
console.log(age);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a default value using `||`,

```js
const person = null
const { age } = person || {}

console.log(age)
```

[`Short circuiting in JavaScript`](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c)